# Using a panel for the homepage?

Tags: 7, panels

I am building a site in Drupal and I'm using the `Panels` module to create my page layouts. I have created the layout that I would like for my homepage and created the content that I'd like in there.

I have set it to 'promoted to homepage' yet, when I visit the homepage, I just get the title and submitted date, and a read more link. The layout isn't being seen, you have to click through in order to see the page.

How can I turn off the 'read more' link and use the panel as the homepage?

Answer (score 2):

Visit `admin/config/system/site-information`, and set the panel's path as the default home page.

Comment: I found that if I went here, `/admin/structure/pages` then I could edit the custom panel-page I created, then configure it as my site home page, which seemed to work. Is this an okay way of doing it?

Comment: Yep, you got it right! As long as it's configured via the panels interface there is no reason that would be incorrect.